# Optimization (loop)

Tags: matlab, optimization

How can I optimize these for loop? I learned about optimizing by using matrix instead of loops, but in this case, I don't know what to do.

```
for j = 2:n
for i = sum(R(1:j-1,1)) : sum(R(1:j,1))
F(1,i) = -s(j,1) * F_0;
end
end
```

Comment: The question would be clearer if you could describe what R, F and F_0 are. Could you please explain or post relevant code?

Comment: In each iteration of `j`, you overwrite `F(1,i)`, so all you see in the result is `F(1,i)` for all `j=n`. That means you can drop the outer for loop and replace it by a constant `j=n`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized form:

```
I = R(1,1):sum(R(:,1));
J = repelem(2:n,[R(2:end-1,1) ;R(end,1)+1]);
F(1,I) = -s(J,1) * F_0;
```

explanation:

You can run the loop with an example data and see how i and j will change

```
n = 7
R = randi([1 5],n,1)
for j = 2:n
    for i = sum(R(1:j-1,1)) : sum(R(1:j,1))
        disp([i j])
    end
end
```

and based on that you can write a vectorized form.